# Can't access SQL Server 2008 via windows service

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an application which connects to SQL Server 2008 via windows service.Basically,windows service pics up a configuration file to get connection details like instance name , user name & password.Currently this windows service is failing to start with following error message :-

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server 
is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Application server and DB server are different machines.I can connect to SQL Server via SSMS from application server without any issue. Also I created a UDL on app server and it also connected fine to DB server. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on my server, the service runs perfectly on my development machine but, when installed on the actual server, I can't connect to the MS-SQL instance. Have you managed to fix this problem by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Check the account under witch windows service is running- most possible that account is not allowed to make connections to other computers.